# How do I get the numbers that do not have a duplicated value in an array of numbers?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to filter an array so that only the unique (distinct) items are left? (not to be confused with removing duplicated items)

I'm looking for something like this:

```js
arrayDistinct([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4])
//=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: @Taplar it just filters out duplicates. the array would be then `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @ambianBeing No, I'm not trying to remove duplicate items. Instead, I want to get the items that were not duplicated in the first place.

Comment: `[...new Set([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4])]`

Comment: @AluanHaddad That returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, which is incorrect. The asker is looking to remove all elements appearing more than once.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, I say `arrayDistinct` and thought, I know what does that. You have basically join the array to itself, in the SQL sense.

Comment: That's not the meaning of "distinct" @RichieBendall. What you want is "unique", un-duplicated numbers.I'd also add this question has a [distinct lack of effort](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: @Liam That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a program that doesn't iterate through the input multiple times or create intermediate state (like counts) to arrive at the solution -

```js
// distinct1.js

function distinct (values = [])
{ const r = new Set(values)   // result
  const s = new Set           // seen
  for (const v of values)
    if (s.has(v))
      r.delete(v)
    else
      s.add(v)
  return Array.from(r)
}

console.log(distinct([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5 ]))
// [ 3, 4, 5 ]
```

*Technically*, the `Set` constructor used above does iterate through the input to create the initial set. We can further optimise by starting with empty sets -

```js
// distinct2.js

function distinct (values = [])
{ const r = new Set         // result
  const s = new Set         // seen
  for (const v of values)
    if (s.has(v))
      continue
    else if (r.has(v))
      (r.delete(v), s.add(v))
    else
      r.add(v)
  return Array.from(r)
}

console.log(distinct([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5 ]))
// [ 3, 4, 5 ]
```

---

To see the big effect small changes like this can make, let's consider a significantly large input. We will generate one million 7-digit numbers and find the distinct values using various approaches -

```js
const rand = n =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * n)

const inrange = (min, max) =>
  rand(max - min + 1) + min

const r =
  Array.from(Array(1e6), _ => inrange(1e6, 1e7-1))

console.log(r)
```

```
[
  5114931, 9106145, 8460777, 4453008, 2388497, 6013688, 2552937,
  1804171, 1264251, 4848368, 9659369, 8420530, 7150842, 3490019,
  9003395, 7645576, 8968872, 3617948, 6780357, 5715769, 7911037,
  3293079, 6173966, 8016471, 3462426, 8048448, 5061586, 8478988,
  1733908, 1007848, 7027309, 7210176, 8598863, 8341131, 4586641,
  5121335, 7157381, 8835726, 5395867, 6145745, 5058377, 5817408,
  6153398, 6514711, 9297841, 7851503, 1678386, 2833373, 9093901,
  6002570, 4512648, 1586990, 9984143, 8618601, 5609095, 8971964,
  9845723, 7884387, 8635795, 3105128, 2764544, 2213559, 5788547,
  8729079, 2176326, 1339145, 8278925, 5598964, 5712291, 2302033,
  3744467, 4555008, 3301943, 5993299, 6499550, 3125444, 5763790,
  6476676, 7920890, 9299943, 5129401, 7414350, 6469143, 2246004,
  6659545, 9269620, 8333459, 2468048, 6420650, 3330098, 7722297,
  6082093, 8883388, 6240800, 8976961, 9192095, 4827011, 4202172,
  9476644, 3786121,
  ... 999900 more items
]
```

Using a cursory `benchmark` program -

```js
function benchmark (f, ...args)
{ console.time(f.name)
  const r = f(...args)
  console.timeEnd(f.name)
  return r 
}
```

We will measure the two solutions in this answer and compare them against another answer in this thread -

```js
benchmark(distinct1, r) // first solution in this answer
benchmark(distinct2, r) // second solution in this answer
benchmark(distinct3, r) // solution from @hev1
```

Results -

```
distinct1: 406.695ms
distinct2: 238.350ms
distinct3: 899.650ms
```

The revised program runs about twice as fast as the first program, because it uses half the amount of iteration. Programs like @hev1's which use multiple iterations and/or allocate additional memory for *each* element result in a longer runtime.

Expand the program below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
// @user633183-1
function distinct1 (values = [])
{ const r = new Set(values)
  const s = new Set
  for (const v of values)
    if (s.has(v))
      r.delete(v)
    else
      s.add(v)
  return Array.from(r)
}

// @user633183-2
function distinct2 (values = [])
{ const r = new Set
  const s = new Set
  for (const v of values)
    if (s.has(v))
      continue
    else if (r.has(v))
      (r.delete(v), s.add(v))
    else
      r.add(v)
  return Array.from(r)
}

// @hev1
const distinct3 = arr => {
  const freq = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc[curr]=(acc[curr]||0)+1,acc), {});
  return arr.filter(x => freq[x] === 1);
}

function benchmark (f, ...args)
{ console.time(f.name)
  const r = f(...args)
  console.timeEnd(f.name)
  return r 
}

const rand = n =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * n)

const inrange = (min, max) =>
  rand(max - min + 1) + min

const r =
  Array.from(Array(1e6), _ => inrange(1e6, 1e7-1))

benchmark(distinct1, r) // 406.695ms
benchmark(distinct2, r) // 238.350ms
benchmark(distinct3, r) // 899.650ms
```

Comment: This distinctly has the small of micro optimisation. I'd be interested to know if you could come up with a real world example for this and exactly how much faster (if any) it was? It's certainly less readable than many of the other answers so I'd want to see a big improvement to bother with this

Comment: Liam feel free to attempt answering the question yourself and/or providing a comparison of the other answers here. For a significantly large input, reducing iteration by half (or more) or freeing up memory alloc/dealloc _per element_, can have a tremendous impact.

Comment: Liam, I added a quick comparison for you. You can decide whether this is a "micro optimisation" :D

Comment: Thanks for adding some data. TBH I do think this this still micro optimsation. Most common or garden tasks are going to be much less than 1 million items and, though I take your point that this is potentially twice as fast, even the slow one takes less than  second. For me, [readability wins here.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler#:~:text=Any%20fool%20can%20write%20code,code%20that%20humans%20can%20understand.).

Comment: But I guess if speed is what you're after and [you're sure that speed is actually important](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil), this is the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

For enhanced performance, you can first iterate over the array once to create an object representing the frequency of each element and then filter the array to get all the elements with a frequency of `1`. This solution runs in `O(n)` time and space.

```js
const arrayDistinct = arr => {
  const freq = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc[curr]=(acc[curr]||0)+1,acc), {});
  return arr.filter(x => freq[x] === 1);
}
console.log(arrayDistinct([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]));
```

For arrays that contain elements of different types that have the same string representation, we can use a `Map` instead of an object to store frequency.

```js
const arrayDistinct = arr => {
  const freq = arr.reduce((map,curr)=>(map.set(curr, (map.get(curr)||0)+1),map), new Map);
  return arr.filter(x => freq.get(x) === 1);
}
console.log(arrayDistinct([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, '1']));
```

Comment: Iterating through `arr` twice (once with `reduce` then again using `filter`) and storing an intermediate integer count for each value is not _best_ performance :D

Comment: @Thank you It sacrifices space for time. Most other solutions involve nested iteration, which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @hev1 A slight problem arises when using strings that would evaluate to the same as numbers: `arrayDistinct(["1", 1])` returns `[]`

Comment: `Map` is the correct data structure if you care about _counting_ the elements, but counting is an indirect (and more costly) way of arriving at the answer. Using `Set` as demonstrated in my answer is faster and uses less space.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const og = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4];
const ogfrequency = {};

/*compute frequency of each elem*/
for (const i of og) {
  ogfrequency[i] = ogfrequency[i] ? ++ogfrequency[i] : 1;
}

/*pass or fail the test of filter based on frequencies collected previously*/
const answer = og.filter((e) => ogfrequency[e] === 1);
console.info("answer::", answer);
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be implemented like so:

```js
const arrayDistinct = array => array.filter(value => array.indexOf(value) === array.lastIndexOf(value))

arrayDistinct([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4])
//=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: @Liam That doesn't answer the question - try it yourself.

Comment: @Liam That finds the duplicates, but does not return only the elements that appeared once.

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```js
const values = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4];

const results = values.filter(value =>
  values.filter(v => v === value).length === 1
);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: nested `filter(_ => ... filter(_ => ...))` spawns process with quadratic time and space

Comment: It's also simple. You can downvote for performance if you like.